# how can I get bootstrap tooltip to show at mouse position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap tooltip, and i was wondering if is possible to make the tooltip show up on mouse position. What i want to do is have the tooltip at the position relative to the mouse pointer on enter.

could that be done using bootstrap tooltip?

Comment: You could have a very small, say 1px x 1px transparent square png element (as an example). Update its position using 'onmousemove' events (perhaps you want to throttle or debounce this to limit how often it fires). Anyway, just set your tooltip on that element and hide/show it dynamically using another event to listen on "enter" keydown/keyup events. It is late at the moment so I will revisit this and provide actual code as an example perhaps tomorrow when I get a chance but figured I would provide my thoughts for now.